# Blackberry 10 Java Apps

Tags: java, blackberry

I have been researching programming apps for Blackberry 10 recently, and am wondering if it is possible to program in Java. I have seen conflicting answers all over the place, but am not sure which to believe. Also, if it is possible, what program should I use? I want the app UI to look as if it was designed solely for Blackberry (Native). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can program a Java Android APK and convert it to the BlackBerry BAR format afterwards. They even offer a plugin for Android Studio.

Comment: It would look like an Android app in that case, correct? (I didn't include that part of the question previously).

Comment: Yes it will look like and Android app. Of course you can make the Android app look like a BlackBerry app but you need a lot of styling then.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "they offer a plug-in." Are you meaning BB?

Comment: Yes, BB offers a plugin for Android Studio that allows converting & starting your Android apps directly on a BB device. https://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/bb_android_studio_plugin_tool.html